# How can I optimize my pyautogui and pytesseract code to press a key faster based on found text?

Tags: python

Is anyone able to help me improve this code. It does not run as fast as I need it to. By the time it presses 'e', it is too late. And by late, I mean by .5 seconds. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pyautogui
import pytesseract
import time

def display_message(message):
    pyautogui.typewrite(message, interval=0.1)

def check_screen_for_words():
    display_message("Program is running.")
    found_Example = False
    found_Example2 = False

    while not (found_Example and found_Example2):
        # Capture screenshot within the specified region
        screen = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(1582, 1402, 2280-1582, 1535-1402))
        screen_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(screen)

        if "Example" in screen_text:
            pyautogui.keyDown('e')
            time.sleep(1.5)  # Hold 'e' key for 1.5 seconds
            pyautogui.keyUp('e')
            found_Example = True

        if "Example2" in screen_text:
            pyautogui.press('e')
            found_Example2 = True

    display_message("Program has completed.")

check_screen_for_words()
```